# typescript - general function to convert string to value which uses string enums

Tags: angular, typescript

I have string enum declared as follows:

```
export namespace BootDeviceSelector {
    export const noChange: 'None' = 'None';
    export type noChange = 'None';
    export const PXE_ISCSI: 'Pxe' = 'Pxe';
    export type PXE_ISCSI = 'Pxe';
}
export type BootDeviceSelector = BootDeviceSelector.noChange | BootDeviceSelector.PXE_ISCSI;
```

In my application I have many more such a sets. I need a general mapping function which converts string (coming from backend) to value (example: `"None"` => `BootDeviceSelector.noChange`). I don't know how to declare parameters and output of function (maybe something better than `any`). I'd expect to pass to this function value to convert and list of values to search in - preferably as namespace name (example: `BootDeviceSelector`).

Or one-liner is good enough, something like this:

```
let a: BootDeviceSelector = (<any>BootDeviceSelector)['Pxe'];
console.log(a);
```

but here I've got `undefined`.

I'm using typescript 2.0.10 and Angular 2.3.1 but I can upgrade, although then I'll leave linting done by `codelyzer` package.

Comment: But what's the point? `BootDeviceSelector.noChange` is `"None"`, and you already get `"None"`.

Comment: `"None"` comes from backend. In application I use `SomeObject.bootDeviceSelector: BootDeviceSelector` - class property of type `BootDeviceSelector`

Comment: There's no difference between `let a = "None"` and `let a = BootDeviceSelector.noChange`. Trying to find the corresponding reference to `None` in `BootDeviceSelector` will gain you nothing as you'll end up with what you started with.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Reverse-Mapping for String Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883072/reverse-mapping-for-string-enums/44896290#44896290). Example:

```
enum BootDeviceSelector {
    noChange = <any>'None',
    PXE_ISCSI = <any>'Pxe'
}

let bds: BootDeviceSelector = BootDeviceSelector.PXE_ISCSI;
```