# Typescript: How to get the enum "name" with its value?

Tags: typescript

I have this enum:

```
export enum myEnum {
  name1 = 'my name',
  name2 = 'my other name',
  name3 = 'other'
}
```

and i have a myEnum object:

```
const x = myEnum.name1;
console.log(x)  // prints 'my name'
```

How can i print 'name1' with my const x? In other words, how to get the enum name 'name1' with a myEnum value 'myEnum.name1'?

**EDIT:**

This is how it looks:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the use case here, and how this will be useful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reverse-Mapping for String Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44883072/reverse-mapping-for-string-enums)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko unfortunately not.

Comment: @Harry it is actually very useful and a very simple use case which u have more or less in every other language. getting the name of enum with its value. what is so weird about it? Java for example does have a method "name()" for its enums exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Can you give an an example of such a use case? I am trying to understand and learn :)

Comment: @Harry one of our endpoints use the same enum, but with different values.. so i have to call this endpoint with the "name" of this enum. so in post request's body you see sth like "{selectedMyEnum: "name1"}"

Comment: ok I get you @akcasoy

Comment: You can create "reverse enum": https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBBCeCi5oG8CwAoKUQEMLAEYoBeKAcjmz2DIBoMtd8AmE8ygewBcALYAJyr46DIcADMbMtz78yGAL4YMAYw4gAzlyj9gANwEbgAWQRI2AeQBGAK2AquAOlBd+AS2AaAFHESQAlI66ACZgKsBeXvy0UADaANbAsDF6OAA2YMAAuv4kAHxQaJg6sakZ2WyJsADcorpcYPwgOrXoCjHICv6tquoaHGnAjmkcAOZR+oYmZgFAA

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings), enums can be reverse-mapped as follows:

```
enum Enum {
    A
}
let a = Enum.A;
let nameOfA = Enum[a]; // "A"
```

To enumerate the values ***and keys*** of the enum, it can effectively be treated as a standard JS object. Here, you might choose to probe it with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
Object.entries(myEnum)
```

will yield an array of key-value pairs:

```
[["name1","my name"],["name2","my other name"],["name3","other"]]
```

Comment: this is the case when an enum does not have a value. but in my case this does not work. Enum[Enum.A] (where A actually has a value like "value"), does not give you the "A"